# Multidementional array declaration

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to set 100 values in a multidementional array to 1 (10x10) but im getting the error

TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

How can I fix this?

````
var unsolvedArray = [[]];

for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    unsolvedArray[i][j] = 1;
  }
}
console.log(unsolvedArray)```
````

Comment: unsolvedArray[0][1] or unsolvedArray[1][0] will be undefined in your case. Same goes for further indices. Try to use .push().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unsolvedArray[0][1]` or `unsolvedArray[1][0]` will be undefined in your case. Same goes for further indices. Try to use `.push()`.

Using your own code:

```
var unsolvedArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
unsolvedArray.push([]); //This is adding the empty array, otherwise unsovledArray[0] will cause error.
  for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    unsolvedArray[i].push(1); //Same logic, unsolvedArray[0][0] will cause error
  }
}
```